# Select multiple max values in mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql-order-by, sql-limit, sql-max

Lets say i have two columns with diffrent values like this:

```
id  |val
1   |  9
7   |  6
7   |  8
```

I want to return the max id, and then find the max value according to the id.
The row I return would be **id: 7 and val: 8.**

How would I write this in Mysql? I am aware of **MAX()** but I cant find any solution to use this with multiple columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the table by `id` descending and then by `val` descending and pick the top row with `LIMIT 1`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY id DESC, val DESC
LIMIT 1
```